# Show Font Awesome Icons In WP Post Editor

Tags: wp-editor

I have added the Font Awesome script and it is being loaded in the source code also. But the icons are not being displayed in the post editor. Any possible solution?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've registered the stylesheet for the editor:

```
add_editor_style( 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
```

This should be in your `functions.php`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style

Comment: A custom plugin with the code would probably be better here than to have it theme dependent?